# Sending data to workers

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor, spmd

I am trying to create a piece of parallel code to speed up the processing of a very large (couple of hundred million rows) array. In order to parallelise this, I chopped my data into 8 (my number of cores) pieces and tried sending each worker 1 piece. Looking at my RAM usage however, it seems each piece is send to each worker, effectively multiplying my RAM usage by 8. A minimum working example:

```
A = 1:16;
for ii = 1:8
    data{ii} = A(2*ii-1:2*ii);
end
```

Now, when I send this data to workers using `parfor` it seems to send the full cell instead of just the desired piece:

```
output = cell(1,8);
parfor ii = 1:8
    output{ii} = data{ii};
end
```

I actually use some function within the `parfor` loop, but this illustrates the case. Does MATLAB actually send the full cell `data` to each worker, and if so, how to make it send only the desired piece?

Comment: If your data is a [sliced variable](http://mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variables.html) it will be "sliced" and only those slices will be transmitted to the workers; are you using sliced variables in  your real code?

Comment: I'm using a cell array in my actual code, as presented here. I'll look into the sliced variable function, thanks.

Comment: Maybe do slicing manually, submitting individual jobs for each piece: http://de.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/submit.html

Comment: Note: the `gather` after the `parfor` loop here is redundant - `gather` is used to convert a `distributed` array into a regular MATLAB array.

Comment: Slicing your variables may definitely be the way to go. We can't help you a lot on telling you if you are slicing it right or not without seeing your code tho.

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior I'm splitting it in exactly the way I presented. I have an `Mx7` array with `M` in the order of hundreds of millions, and chop that into eight (my number of cores) pieces, then store each piece in a cell, just as presented.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my personal experience, I found that using `parfeval` is better regarding memory usage than `parfor`. In addition, your problem seems to be more breakable, so you can use `parfeval` for submitting more smaller jobs to MATLAB workers.

Let's say that you have `workerCnt` MATLAB workers to which you are gonna handle `jobCnt` jobs. Let `data` be a cell array of size `jobCnt x 1`, and each of its elements corresponds to a data input for function `getOutput` which does the analysis on data. The results are then stored in cell array `output` of size `jobCnt x 1`.

in the following code, jobs are assigned in the first `for` loop and the results are retrieved in the second `while` loop. The boolean variable `doneJobs` indicates which job is done.

```
poolObj = parpool(workerCnt);
jobCnt = length(data); % number of jobs
output = cell(jobCnt,1);
for jobNo = 1:jobCnt
    future(jobNo) = parfeval(poolObj,@getOutput,...
        nargout('getOutput'),data{jobNo});
end
doneJobs = false(jobCnt,1);
while ~all(doneJobs)
    [idx,result] = fetchnext(future);
    output{idx} = result;
    doneJobs(idx) = true;
end
```

Also, you can take this approach one step further if you want to save up more memory. What you could do is that after fetching the results of a done job, you can delete the corresponding member of `future`. The reason is that this object stores all the input and output data of `getOutput` function which probably is going to be huge. But you need to be careful, as deleting members of `future` results index shift.

The following is the code I wrote for this porpuse.

```
poolObj = parpool(workerCnt);
jobCnt = length(data); % number of jobs
output = cell(jobCnt,1);
for jobNo = 1:jobCnt
    future(jobNo) = parfeval(poolObj,@getOutput,...
        nargout('getOutput'),data{jobNo});
end
doneJobs = false(jobCnt,1);
while ~all(doneJobs)
    [idx,result] = fetchnext(future);
    furure(idx) = []; % remove the done future object
    oldIdx = 0;
    % find the index offset and correct index accordingly
    while oldIdx ~= idx
        doneJobsInIdxRange = sum(doneJobs((oldIdx + 1):idx));
        oldIdx = idx
        idx = idx + doneJobsInIdxRange;
    end
    output{idx} = result;
    doneJobs(idx) = true;
end
```

Answer (score 5):

The comment from @m.s is correct - when `parfor` *slices* an array, then each worker is sent only the slice necessary for the loop iterations that it is working on. However, you might well see the RAM usage increase beyond what you originally expect as unfortunately copies of the data are required as it is passed from the client to the workers via the `parfor` communication mechanism.

If you need the data only on the workers, then the best solution is to create/load/access it only on the workers if possible. It sounds like you're after data parallelism rather than task parallelism, for which `spmd` is indeed a better fit (as @Kostas suggests).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use the `spmd` command of MATLAB.

You can write code almost as it would be for a non-parallel implementation and also have access to the current worker by the `labindex` "system" variable.

Have a look here:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/spmd.html

And also at this SO question about `spmd` vs `parfor`:

[SPMD vs. Parfor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385534/spmd-vs-parfor)

Comment: Whilst using SPMD might help the code, it circumvents the question rather than answering it. I want to know how to properly send my data to workers without ridiculous overhead, so I can use it in other pieces of code as well.

Comment: Using spmd or parfor does not matter in terms of RAM usage, but the code using spmd takes ~1.2 times longer than the parfor implementation.

Comment: If you use the same logic as in the provided example, then you have something wrong in your code. Since it would require an almost debug of your code to see the actual error, I suggested a quick alternative to solve your problem. If you specificaly require parfor, then you should post the whole code.

Comment: I do not get an error, I merely suspect the data gets send to all workers and thereby multiplied. The question thus is not to debug my code, but to understand the working's of how matlab distributes data over workers.