# MATLAB: Is it inefficient to use parfor (parallel for loop) within a while loop.

Tags: matlab, parfor, mcmc

I'm having a trouble doing MCMC(Monte Carlo Markov Chain). So for MCMC, say I will run 10000 iterations, then within each iteration, I will draw some parameters. But in each iteration, I have some individual data which are independently, so I can do parfor. However, the problem is, it seems the time to finish one iteration just grows quickly as MCMC goes on. Soon, it's extremely time consuming. 
My question is: is there any efficient way to combine parfor and while loop?

I have the following pseudo-code:

```
r=1;
while r<10000
parfor i=1:I
  make draws from proposal distribution 
  calculate acceptance rate  
  accept or reject current draw
end

r=r+1;
end
```

Comment: This pseudo-code makes no sense, since you'd just replace the `while` with a `for` over 10000 entries. Besides, unless your iterations *within*  the loop are very big, `parfor` will actually slow your code down, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146555/saving-time-and-memory-using-parfor-in-matlab/32146700#32146700)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launching lots of separate `parfor` loops can be inefficient if each loop duration is small. Unfortunately, as you are probably aware, you cannot `break` out of a `parfor` loop. One alternative might be to use [`parfeval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfeval.html). The idea would be to make many `parfeval` calls (but not too many), and then you can terminate when you have sufficient results.

[This (fairly long) blog article](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/12/09/getting-data-from-a-web-api-in-parallel/) shows an example of using `parfeval` in a situation where you might wish to terminate the computations early.