# Parallel calculation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I want to make my Matlab project faster using Parallel Computing Toolbox.
In my PC there are 2 processors with 12 cores (each processor). So, I have 24 cores.
The problem is that Matlab always finds only 12 cores. As I understand it uses only cores in one processor, where Matlab's project is running. But I want to use all my 24 cores. Is it possible? If yes, how can I do it?
I guess, I should build cluster, but for cluster I have to buy MATLAB Distributed Computing Server. I don’t want to do it because I don’t want to use a lot of computers...just only my PC with 24 cores...
Thank you for your time and consideration

Comment: post the code of how you have set up your parallel session

Comment: Are you sure it is 12 *cores* in each processor, and not 6 cores with 12 threads?

Comment: I suspect you have two hexa-core processors with multi/hyper threading. That makes it *virtually* 24 cores, but MATLAB sees only physical cores.

Comment: I’m sure, I have very powerful computer. But the main point of my question is “How can I use all threads of computer with Matlab?”.
Matlab write me:
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ... connected to 12 workers

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways to determine the amount of workers in your parallel pool. E.g. using [`parpool`](http://mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parpool.html):

```
parpool(poolsize)
```

opens a parallel pool with `poolsize` workers, provided that number of workers is possible on your machine.

The other possibility is to go to the home->preference->parallel preferences tab and within there create a profile containing the number of workers you want. You can then call a pool using:

```
parpool(profilename,poolsize)
```

where `profilename` is the name you gave to that pool profile. The `poolsize` argument is optional here, if you do not specify it, it will use the default number of workers as specified under the parallel preferences.

Note that [`matlabpool`](http://mathworks.com/help/mdce/release-notes.html?searchHighlight=matlabpool) was removed in R2014a, so you cannot use that anymore to open your pool. Another possibility is [`gcp`](http://mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gcp.html), but this is mainly to Get Current Pool and the parameters of that pool.

As a remark: always make sure your code is the fastest possible in *serial*  before trying to go parallel. Parallel computing is not like a magic want which you wave around to improve speeds, it's a specialised tool which works optimal on efficient programs, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146555/saving-time-and-memory-using-parfor-in-matlab/32146700#32146700).

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I have already changed the number of threads. Parallel Computing Toolbox Preferences don't help me. Matlab don't want to use more threads

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? As @AnonMe pointed out, with the removal of `matlabpool` the maximum of 12 workers was removed. Thus, if you use version R2013b or older, you won't be able to use more workers.

Comment: I use Matlab R2013b. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB (and Parallel Computing Toolbox) *by default* consider only "real" cores, and not hyper-threaded cores. This is because experience has shown that this actually improves performance in most cases. However, you can override MATLAB's default choice by executing:

```
maxNumCompThreads(24)
```

Or, for Parallel Computing Toolbox, you can use the [Cluster Profile Manager](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/clusters-and-cluster-profiles.html#f5-16540) to edit your `'local'` profile, and set the number of workers to 24.

**EDIT:** Just noticed that the OP is using R2013b. In which case, you cannot use more than 12 local workers. Upgrading to R2014a or later will fix that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is really useful. Now I understand that I can’t use more workers with my Matlab version. So, Now I can start the CUDA-part. =)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Matlab version, it may be licencing issue. For older versions you need the  MATLAB Distributed Computing Server (MDCS). 
The limit to 12 workers was removed with R2014a.