# Parallelize MATLAB for loop to calculate MLE

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor, mle

I am attempting to speed up my MATLAB code by using `parfor`, however, I am doing it incorrectly. My code is rather simple, I am fitting some data using MATLAB's built-in `mle` function by using varying initial guesses for the mean (`mm`) and variance (`vv`). `onestagepdf2` is my probability density function.

Here is the code snippit:

```
mm=linspace(.1, 1, 2); % mean
vv=linspace(.1, 2, 2); % variance
N=length(mm);
n=length(vv);

pd=zeros(n*N,2);
ld = NaN*ones(n*N,1);

options = statset('MaxIter',10000, 'MaxFunEvals',10000);

parfor i=1:N  % pick a mean
    m=mm(i);
    parfor j=1:n  %  pick a variance
        v=vv(j);
        x0=[m,v];
        [p,conf1]=mle(data,'pdf',@onestagepdf2,'start',x0, 'upperbound', [Inf Inf],'lowerbound',[0 0],'options',options)
        pd(n*(i-1)+j,:)=p;  % store parameter values from mle
        l=onestagepdf2(data,p(1),p(2)); % evaluate pdf with parameter values
        ld(n*(i-1)+j)=sum(log(l));  % store likelihood value

    end
end
```

The error that I receive is:

> 'The variable pd in a parfor cannot be classified.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd = zeros(n, N, 2); %initialise culprits
ld= zeros(n,N);
parfor ii=1:N  % pick a mean
    m=mm(ii);
    for jj=1:n  %  Parallellise the second parfor
        v=vv(jj);
        x0=[m,v];
        [p,conf1]=mle(data,'pdf',@onestagepdf2,'start',x0, 'upperbound', [Inf Inf],'lowerbound',[0 0],'options',options)
        pd(ii, jj, :) = p;=p;  % store parameter values from mle
        l=onestagepdf2(data,p(1),p(2)); % evaluate pdf with parameter values
        ld(ii,jj)=sum(log(l));  % store likelihood value

    end
end
```

Your `pd` was indeed the culprit, as @Trilarion stated, for the error you got. Probably `ld` also isn't too great, with the same syntax, so initialise that as well. This happened because [`parfor`](http://mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html) wants to know what the size of all variables within the loop is *before executing*. That this is a fixed maximum size is unknown to MATLAB, since you are using the loop variables to "change" the size.

Probably you had "orange wiggles" below those two lines (like spell-check errors) when you ran this as a `for` loop saying that "pd appears to be growing in size each iteration. Please consider preallocating for speed". This is *required* by `parfor`, since the order of iteration is not sequential it is impossible to grow arrays this way.

Secondly, you cannot nest `parfor` loops. You can use things like a function with a `parfor` and run that within the `parfor`, but that won't get you a speed-up since you are already using all your workers.

See [Saving time and memory using parfor in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146555/saving-time-and-memory-using-parfor-in-matlab/32146700#32146700) for more general information on `parfor` especially on speed.

Comment: I need to initialize `pd` and `ld` inside the `parfor` loop as opposed to outside?

Comment: hum, no. Indeed you need to initialise them outside, my bad, I'll update the post.

Comment: `n*(i-1)+j` is not larger than `n*N` here, so the size of the variable is not growing. It's just that Matlab is not sure about it.

Comment: @Trilarion that's precisely what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

You want a sliced, output variable but Matlab is not clever enough to detect that `n*(i-1)+j` is actually reasonable and won't interfere with an asynchronous evaluation.

Just do it as separate dimensions

```
pd = zeros(n, N, 2);
...
  % in the loop
  pd(i, j, :) = p;
```

That will work.

Please note, that Matlab does not allow nested parfors. However, you also do not need them if `N` is larger than the number of workers. See also the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/nesting-and-flow-in-parfor-loops.html).

Comment: The same goes for ld.

Comment: @Adriaan With say 4-8 workers and N probably larger than this the asker does not need a second parfor anyway. But he still needs to expand the dimensionality of pd and ld in order to get the outer parfor to work.

Comment: that seemed to fix the issue. I do have a follow up question: when I print `max(ld)`, it prints the maximum value twice, i.e., `-746.8349 -746.8349`. Could you explain why?

Comment: @user3603290 If you have a new question that is sufficiently different from this one then please ask [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If one of the answers in this post solved your problem then please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).