# Executing time for a function in parallel

Tags: matlab, function, timer, parallel-processing, try-catch

I am currently working on parallel timing function, as a timing threshold, that can be applied to the main function. A maximum running time is needed. Once the threshold is reached, the main function would break and enter the next loop.
My original idea was to call `timer` from another independent function so that a parallel function would be possible. But it fails to do so.

```
function timeStop()
time = cputime;
time = cputime-time;
a = timer;
set (a, 'executionMode', 'fixedRate')
set (a,'timerfcn','disp(time)')
start(a)
timeStop = time;
end
```

Then calling this `timeStop`,

```
function fucx()
for i = 1:3
    for j = 1:3
        for k = 1:3
            try
                %MainFuc()

                timeStop
                if (timeStop>60) % in seconds
                    disp('RunOutOfTime: Program terminated');
                    stop(a)
                    break;
                end;

            catch
                %%Err()
            end
        end
     end
end
end
```

It is a huge collection of model setting, study, and solutions in `MainFunc()`, without loops. I was thinking about directly putting the `tic/toc` function into the `MainFuc()`. But I am not sure whether MATLAB internally would work the way that I want it to. Because I do not know which step or code line the infinite time was trapped in `MainFunc()`. I cannot simply put the `tic/toc` function with it if it is not determined in parallel.

I have considered using `tic/toc`, but I was told that internally MATLAB would only know the running time after the full execution of `MainFuc()`. I am not sure if this is true, but found posts with a similar meaning in different locations.

Comment: I did `tic/toc` inside a `parfor` loop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146555/saving-time-and-memory-using-parfor-in-matlab/32146700#32146700 Seemed a reasonable result, provided you don't want millisecond accuracy.

Comment: You certainly can't abort `MainFuc()` after calling it from outside (i.e. from `funcx()` within the loop). So you'd have to place the if-statement inside of `MainFunc()` and break within there as soon as a maximum execution time is over. Furthermore you'd have to declare `time ` within `timeStop()` as a persistent variable and initialize it properly before using. The way you do it now will not measure the runtime between two consecutive calls to `timeStop()` as you wish to do it.

Comment: The goal is to make a parallel running TIMING function to terminate the infinite running loops and proceed to next one. It seems parfor only works to partition the MainFunc() into concurrent jobs.

Comment: Cant simply put the if-statement inside the MainFunc(). Because we do not know which line inside the MainFunc() is causing the infinite time issue.