# How to average independent consecutive blocks of an array as fast as possible?

Tags: arrays, matlab, performance, optimization, average

Here is the problem:

```
data = 1:0.5:(8E6+0.5);
```

An array of 16 million points, needs to be averaged every 10,000 elements.

Like this:

```
x = mean(data(1:10000))
```

But repeated N times, where N depends on the number of elements we average over

```
range = 10000;

N = ceil(numel(data)/range);
```

My current method is this:

```
data(1) = mean(data(1,1:range));
for i = 2:N
    data(i) = mean(data(1,range*(i-1):range*i));
end
```

How can the speed be improved?

*N.B: We need to overwrite the original array of data (essentially bin the data and average it)*

Comment: Have you tried using this code but with `parfor` not `for`?

Comment: Yeah but that seemed to take on the order of seconds, rather than ms which is what this gives, my CPU is only a duo core. It might have taken so long because it did not setup the parallel pool in advance?

Comment: @JCW yes; always open the pool before timeing. See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32146700/5211833) on speed-up using `parfor`. I wouldn't be surprised that even after pre-opening the pool the vectorised solution is faster though; as all functions are multithreaded and you have only 2 cores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = 1:0.5:(8E6-0.5); % Your data, actually 16M-2 elements
N = 1e4; % Amount to average over
tmp = mod(numel(data),N); % find out whether it fits
data = [data nan(1,N-tmp)]; % add NaN if necessary
data2=reshape(data,N,[]); % reshape into a matrix
out = nanmean(data2,1); % get average over the rows, ignoring NaN
```

Visual confirmation that it works using `plot(out)`

[image]

*Note that technically you can't do what you want if `mod(numel(data),N)` is not equal to 0, since then you'd have a remainder. I elected to average over everything in there, although ignoring the remainder is also an option.*

If you're sure `mod(numel(data),N)` is zero every time, you can leave all that out and reshape directly. I'd not recommend using this though, because if your `mod` is not 0, this will error out on the `reshape`:

```
data = 1:0.5:(8E6+0.5); % 16M elements now
N = 1e4; % Amount to average over
out = sum(reshape(data,N,[]),1)./N; % alternative
```

Comment: Thanks, this is faster, on my PC making the time it takes change from 130 ms to 100 ms, but we need it to be even faster, around 15-30 ms, or a factor of ~5.

Comment: @JCW I'm rather certain `mean` and `nanmean` are multithreaded, and reshaping matrices is almost free in MATLAB. That means that probably the only way to speed up further is to buy a better computer.

Comment: @JCW do you have an NVIDIA GPU and the distributed computing toolbox?

Comment: Is there no way this could be made any faster? (without upgrading hardware)

Comment: @AnderBiguri No I have Intel HD Graphics, however I do have access to all the MATLAB Add-ons

Comment: @JCW Using `sum(data2,1,'omitnan')/N` instead of `nanmean(data2,1)` might be a little faster

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, that decreased it to 89ms !

Comment: @JCW I'm thinking that the last chunk should not be divided by `N`. You need to correct the last one

Comment: @Adriaan your last edit using `sum(reshape(data,N,[]),1,'omitnan')./N;` decreased the runtime down to 49 ms !

I should note in that most cases my mod will be 0 as these parameters and ratios would be setup in advance

Comment: @JCW that's all nice and well, but as I said, that's sort-of dangerous. Check the updated version; the `omitnan` can be omitted as well (pun intended)

Comment: @Adriaan The only issue with this solution is that it does not overwrite the original data, which is very important for us. I could add a `clear data` to the end but this itself takes a few extra ms.

I also understand that you cannot use reshape as `data = reshape(data,...)`

Comment: @JCW then you use `data = sum(reshape(data,N,[]),1)./N;`? Assigning output to a variable should've been one of the first things you learned when starting MATLAB. I don't like to overwrite my initial data with averaged data, as I might need to get back to the original at some point. But yes, you can do that and it will probably be faster still, as you save memory + creating a variable

Comment: Ah my mistake, the whole point of this averaging is to save memory/decrease the number of points we're storing due to the large amount of data we're handling

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit wasteful, but you can use `movmean` (which will handle the endpoints the way you want it to) and then subsample the output:

```
y = movmean(x, [0 9999]);
y = y(1:10000:end);
```

Even though this is wasteful (you're computing a lot of elements you don't need), it appears to outperform the `nanmean` approach (at least on my machine).

=====================

There's also the option to just compensate for the extra elements you added:

```
x = 1:0.5:(8E6-0.5);
K = 1e4;
Npad = ceil(length(x)/K)*K - length(x);
x((end+1):(end+Npad)) = 0;
y = mean(reshape(x, K, []));
y(end) = y(end) * K/(K - Npad);
```

Answer (score 0):

reshape the data array into a 10000XN matrix, then compute the mean of each column using the mean function.

Comment: Doesn't work; `numel(data) = 15,999,998`, so reshaping can't happen

Comment: Appending zeros changes the average

Comment: Only for the last column, just calculate that one separately without the zeros

Comment: That's a little more involved than you'd think on first glance (see my answer). Without writing any code, this looks a lot like a comment to me.