# Using a for loop inside a parallel for loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, nested-loops, parfor

I am trying to use a `for` loop inside of a parfor loop in Matlab.
The `for` loop is equivalent to the ballode example in [here](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/mw/matlab-ex84325677-simple-event-location-a-bouncing-ball).
Inside the `for` loop a function `ballBouncing` is called which is a system of 6 differential equations.

So, what I am trying to do is to use 500 different sets of parameter values for the ODE system and run it, but for each parameter set, a sudden impulse is added, which is handled through the code in 'for' loop.

However, I don't understand how to implement this using a `parfor` and a `for` loop as below.
I could run this code by using two `for` loops but when the outer loop is made to be a `parfor` it gives the errors,
`the PARFOR loop cannot run due to the way variable results is used`,
`the PARFOR loop cannot run due to the way variable y0 is used` and
`Valid indices for results are restricted in PARFOR loops`

```
results=NaN(500,100);
x=rand(500,10);

parfor j=1:500

    bouncingTimes=[10,50];%at time 10 a sudden impulse is added
    refine=2;
    tout=0;
    yout=y0;%initial conditions of ODE system
    paras=x(j,:);%parameter values for the ODE 
    for i=1:2
        tfinal=bouncingTimes(i);
        [t,y]=ode45(@(t,y)ballBouncing(t,y,paras),tstart:1:tfinal,y0,options);
        nt=length(t);
        tout=[tout;t(2:nt)];
        yout=[yout;y(2:nt,:)];

        y0(1:5)=y(nt,1:5);%updating initial conditions with the impulse
        y0(6)=y(nt,6)+paras(j,10);

        options = odeset(options,'InitialStep',t(nt)-t(nt-refine),...
                                 'MaxStep',t(nt)-t(1));
        tstart =t(nt);
    end

    numRows=length(yout(:,1));
    results(1:numRows,j)=yout(:,1);

end
results;
```

Can someone help me to implement this using a `parfor` outer loop.

Comment: [`parfor` is not a magic wand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32146555/5211833), please let that be clear first. Vectorisation might be better. As to the specific here: MATLAB cannot determine **before** each calculation what the length of `numRows` will be, thus it does not know in advance where a specific iteration needs to be saved. If the length of `numRows` is variable, either restructure the code to make it constant, or save in a cell, collecting at the end to the correct indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing the assignment into `results` is relatively straightforward - what you need to do is ensure you always assign a whole column. Here's how I would do that:

```
% We will always need the full size of results in dimension 1
numRows = size(results, 1);
parfor j = ...
    yout = ...; % variable size
    yout(end:numRows, :) = NaN; % Expand if necessary
    results(:, j) = yout(1:numRows, 1); % Shrink 'yout' if necessary
end
```

However, `y0` is harder to deal with - the iterations of your `parfor` loop are not order-independent because of the way you're passing information from one iteration to the next. `parfor` can only handle loops where the iterations are order-independent.