# Parallellising the factorisation of triangle numbers

Tags: matlab, performance, parallel-processing, factors, parfor

The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. So the 7<sup>th</sup> triangle number would be `1+2+3+4+5+6+7 = 28`. The first ten terms would be: `1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55`. The factors contained in the first four triangle numbers are:

```
1: 1
3: 1, 3
6: 1, 2, 3, 6
10: 1, 2, 5, 10
```

We see that `6` is the first triangle number to have over four divisors.

In order to find the first triangle number with over 500 divisors, I wrote the following code:

```matlab
s1=0;
s2=0;
A=zeros(1,2);
for i=1:4000
    s1=i+s1;
    s2=0;
    for n=1:s1
        if rem(s1,n)==0
            s2=s2+1;
        end
    end
    if s2>=500
        A=[s1 s2];
        disp(A)
    end
end
```

I would like to speed up this code using `parfor` instead of `for` on the outer loop. However, I get the error:

> Error: The variable s1 is perhaps intended as a reduction variable, but is actually an uninitialized temporary.
>
> See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Temporary Variables Intended as Reduction Variables".

How can I parallellise this code?

Answer (score 6):

If performance is an issue you can use this code:

```
ii = 1;
while 1
    tn = ii*(ii+1)/2;                  %compute the next triangular number
    fa = factor(tn);                   %prime factorization
    nb = prod(histc(fa,unique(fa))+1); %number of divisor
    if nb > 500
       fprintf('there is %d divisors for %d\n',nb,tn)
       break
    end
    ii = ii+1;
end
```

And you will found that 76576500 is the answer.

The prime factorization `factor` is way faster than finding all the divisors with the `divisors` function.

So we can compute `factor(n)` that will output:

```
x1*n1, x2*n2, x3*n3...
```

for example `factor(60)` give:

`2   2   3   5`

or

`2x2,1x3,1x5`

- There is **3** ways to use the prime factor 2: `2^0`, `2^1` or `2^2`.
- There is **2** ways to use the prime factor 3: `3^0`, `3^1`
- There is **2** ways to use the prime factor 5: `5^0`, `5^1`

So we know that 60 have 3*2*2 = 12 divisors, because the prime factor can be combined in 12 different ways.

Comment: I would add to this answer the time it takes to execute this algorithm (even though such a timing is mostly system-dependent, it would still give some idea). On my system it takes a bit less than 1s.

Comment: Ho and I just found that those highly composite triangular number have an [OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A076711)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot parallelise this, as it is recursive: `s1 = i + s1`.

`parfor` executes your loop in random order, thus it is not known what value `s1` will have in iteration `n`, as its value explicitly depends on its value in iteration `n-1`.

Instead of doing a `for` loop here, I'd go for a `while` loop with the condition `s2<500`. Then as soon as you go over the desired threshold, your loop will stop, thus you limit the number of necessary iterations to the bare minimum.

---

Note that `parfor` is not a magic wand. The overhead of launching the parallel pool will probably be larger than the actual computation time of this short loop. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32146555/5211833) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32095552/5211833) for background information on how `parfor` works and how to write suitable code for it.